# why dosen't this vector give me the same output as the array?

Tags: c++, vector

If a vector is just a more functional array , then just like an array does it store the address of the base element in it's name ? why did I not get the value of the element stored in the specified index position and got the complete string as output instead ?
Here's my code!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> v(20,"hello");
     char a[]={"hello"};

    cout<<v[1]<<"\n"; //this gives hello as the output

    cout<<a[1];       //this gives e


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `std::vector<std::string>` is not even close to being the same as `char []`, since it would be a collection of strings instead of one single string (each element of `v` is a `std::string` and each element of `a` is a `char`).

Comment: `vector<string> v(20,"hello");` you are creating 20 std::strings and printing the second one. `char a[]={"hello"};` you are creating a char array and printing the second char.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're defining entirely different types here.

```
vector<string> v(20,"hello");
```

This creates a vector of 20 strings, each initialized to contain "hello". Each element of the vector is a complete string.

```
char a[]={"hello"};
```

This creates one (C-style) string containing "hello". Each element of the array is a single character.

Naturally, when you ask to print out a string, the entire string is printed out. Likewise, when you ask to print out a single character, a single character is printed out.

Answer (score 3):

`std::vector<string>` is a container of `strings`. Hence, first element is the whole string, second element is another whole string and so on. While a `char[]` is a container of `characters`. Hence, the first element is a character, second element is another character and so on.

Answer (score 1):

*why did I not get the value of the element stored in the specified index position and got the complete string as output instead ?*

Because you use string type in a vector instead of char.

change

```
vector<string> v(20,"hello");
```

to

```
vector<char> v = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

and you will get 'e'.

Answer (score 1):

v[1] is the [1] member if a vector of strings, You have initialized that member to "hello". a[1] is the [1] member of `a`, which you have initialized to `'h','e','l','l','o',0`.

Each of the members of `v` is a complete string. Each of the member of `a` are single characters.